# Image deleted in database after editing

Tags: image, zend-framework

I am using Zend Framework 1.11 and after editing a record, the image file fields is emptied as well even though no other image is uploaded.

I have solved before this problem with mysql using this in the sql query:

```
image=ifnull(%s, image)
```

And worked perfectly. I am working with Zend now and I am not sure how this can be done. Anybody can help please?

Controller code:

```
$input = $form->getValues();
        $item = Doctrine::getTable('Tcc_Model_Item')
            ->find($input['article_id']);

        $item->fromArray($input);
        $item->save();
```

Update is done using a doctrine model.

form field is:

```
$image = new Zend_Form_Element_File('image');
 $image->setLabel('Image')
        ->addValidator('IsImage')
        ->setDestination('../public/uploads')
        ->addValidator('Size', false, '404800')
        ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif')
        ->addValidator('ImageSize', false, array(
                        'minwindth' => 50,
                        'minheight' => 50,
                        'maxwidth' => 250,
                        'maxheight' => 250))
     ->setOptions(array('class' => 'create'));
```

Comment: You need to post your code that edits the record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought to answer to my own question since I found a solution myself that my be of help to some else.

So what I did to solve this problem is:

1. added an hidden field to the form used to edit like this:

   $image = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('image');
2. changed to image file field (the new image to upload) with a different name like this:

   $image2 = new Zend_Form_Element_File('image2');

This way when editing the hidden field will contain the info of the "image" field if there is one.

Then in the controller I simply have a if/else statement just before the save() like this:

```
if(!empty($input['image2']))
       { 
            $item->image = $input['image2']; 
    } else { 
            $item->image = $input['image'];
        }


 $item->save();
```

Hope it helps others with same issue.